# How to enable AD authentication with Kerberos on Linux (Debian)?

Tags: linux, active-directory, debian, authentication, kerberos

I want local users to be able to log in to a Linux server using their Windows domain (AD) passwords. (All local accounts have a matching userid in AD).

I've installed `libpam-krb5`, and the main settings in `/etc/krb5.conf` seem ok:

```
default_realm = FOO.COMPANY.COM
kdc = controller.foo.company.com
```

These settings work fine on another Linux box (Ubuntu); everything should be ok in the AD server.

As I don't know/remember, my question is, **what else needs to be tweaked on the Linux server to get AD passwords to work when users try to log in**?

The server is running Debian 5.0.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right, got it working with some help from a colleague. The only additional configuration file that needed tweaking was **`/etc/pam.d/common-auth`**.

The original configuration was:

```
auth    required    pam_unix.so nullok_secure
```

We changed it to:

```
auth    [success=2 default=ignore]      pam_krb5.so minimum_uid=1000
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure try_first_pass
auth    requisite                       pam_deny.so
auth    required                        pam_permit.so
```

AD passwords now work fine when logging on to the server.

Comment: This page looks like a useful resource btw: http://developer.novell.com/wiki/index.php/HOWTO:_Configure_Ubuntu_for_Active_Directory_Authentication (It also covers handling all account management in AD, unlike in our case.)

Answer (score -3):

use google

http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/battista/documentation/winbind/index.html
http://www.alethe.com/brad/2005/08/active-directory-authentication/
http://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_&_Active_Directory
http://blog.scottlowe.org/2007/01/15/active-directory-integration-index/

Comment: The point of ServerFault is to consolidate knowledge relevant to this field. Eventually "Use Google" should be replaced by "Use ServerFault."

Comment: @sh-beta: What about when google takes you to serverfault?